# how to fix kivy background image is white

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to add a background image for my kivy app but when i run the code it shows a white image instead of the real image and i'm sure that the image is in the same place i used import os getcwd() func

```
Manager:

    HomePage:
    SignupPage:
    AtmPage:

<HomePage>:

    name: 'home'

    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'atm.png'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kivy Screen » Basic Usage](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#basic-usage)

> By default, a [Screen](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen) displays nothing: it’s just a
>   [RelativeLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html#kivy.uix.relativelayout.RelativeLayout).

The attribute, `source` is usually associated to an [Image](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html) widget.

## Solution

Add an `Image` widget as child of `<HomePage>:`

### Snippets - kv file

```
<HomePage>:

    name: 'home'

    Image:    
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: 'atm.png'
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder


runTouchApp(Builder.load_string("""
Manager:

<Manager@ScreenManager>:
    HomePage:
    SignupPage:
    AtmPage:

<HomePage@Screen>:

    name: 'home'

    Image:    
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                # source: 'atm.png'
                source: "./images/Kilauea-Hawaii.jpeg"

<SignupPage@Screen>:
    Label:
        text: 'Signup Page'

<AtmPage@Screen>:
    Label:
        text: 'ATM Page'
"""))
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: [If you want to say "thank you", vote on or accept that person's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

[If you accept someone else's answer: You gain +2 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)